# How will the vaccine be given in the US?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, vaccine

The UK decision has been to go for one-jab followed by a 12-week wait for the second - based on the theory that it is better for overall public health to begin by getting  one-shot into twice the number of people.

However Pfizer (whose first shot I was given on Sunday) seem hesitant about endorsing this, but  AstraZeneca less reluctant.

The other advantage of AZ is that theirs is only a fraction of the cost, and can be stored at domestic fridge temperature.

How will the Pfizer vaccine be given in the US - one shot + 3 weeks wait, or one shot + 12weeks?

Will they be using any AZ?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the Food and Drug Administration (FDA) has [only approved two vaccines for use](https://www.fda.gov/emergency-preparedness-and-response/coronavirus-disease-2019-covid-19/covid-19-vaccines) in the US – Pfizer-BioNTech and Moderna. News reports have noted that the AstraZeneca vaccine [may not be available anytime soon](https://www.businessinsider.com/when-will-astrazeneca-covid-vaccine-be-approved-in-us-2021-1).

Regarding the scheduling of the vaccine doses, the FDA continues to [recommend two doses (as of Jan 4)](https://www.fda.gov/news-events/press-announcements/fda-statement-following-authorized-dosing-schedules-covid-19-vaccines):

> The available data continue to support the use of two specified doses of each authorized vaccine at specified intervals. For the Pfizer-BioNTech COVID-19 vaccine, the interval is 21 days between the first and second dose. And for the Moderna COVID-19 vaccine, the interval is 28 days between the first and second dose.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> We know that some of these discussions about changing the dosing schedule or dose are based on a belief that changing the dose or dosing schedule can help get more vaccine to the public faster. However, making such changes that are not supported by adequate scientific evidence may ultimately be counterproductive to public health.

The Center for Diseases Prevention and Control (CDC) also [states the same guidelines](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/covid-19/info-by-product/index.html) on their website.

[Pfizer said in a statement](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-vaccine-pfizer/pfizer-says-it-has-second-doses-of-covid-19-shot-on-hand-expects-no-us-supply-problems-idUSKBN29K2LR) that it has second doses on hand, despite media reports that the federal government [does not have a stockpile of vaccines](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-usa/trump-administration-accused-of-deception-in-pledging-release-of-vaccine-stockpile-idUSKBN29K2H4).

> “Operation Warp Speed has asked us to start shipping second doses only recently,” the spokeswoman said. “As a result, we have on hand all the second doses of the previous shipments to the US.”

The incoming Biden administration has announced plans to release most available doses first but [employ the Defense Production Act](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/01/17/biden-cdc-pick-confident-theres-enough-covid-vaccine-to-meet-target-amid-confusion-over-stockpile.html) to ramp up production to [ensure sufficient second shots](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/01/14/biden-covid-advisor-says-plan-to-release-most-vaccine-doses-wont-cause-shortage-of-second-shots.html).

> The Biden administration’s plan to release nearly every available dose of Pfizer’s and Moderna’s coronavirus vaccines to states shouldn’t cause any supply issues down the road, a member of President-elect Joe Biden’s Covid-19 advisory board said Thursday.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> Barring some unforeseen “manufacturing snafu,” the Biden administration is “confident” there won’t be problems getting people their second shots on time, she said.